# How to view the last ran sql query from SqlClient data provider on Sql server 2000?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2000, sqlclient

Although I have been able to see the last ran query which is a Stored Procedure executed but I didn't get the parameters values with which the SP was invoked. Rather I got the following:

```
StoredProcedureName;1
```

from the following command:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(SPID)
```

Where I got the SPID by viewing it in the ObjectExplorer->Management->ActivityMonitor

Is there any way I can get the complete text including the parameters with which the SP was executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer may not be what you are looking for, as it doesn't really answer your question, I took a leap of thought and ended up thinking this might help.

I don't know how many queries you have and how big your program is... but for debugging purposes I wanted to do something similar for all of my queries, both plain text and stored procedures.  So I wrote a simple wrapper class that lets me execute plain text queries/stored procs with and without parameters.  Then, if an execption occurs, I trap it, build a new custom exception with the original exception plus the query that was executed and all parameters, and return it all in a custom message.  I'm using Oracle in my wrapper but it's almost exactly the same:

```
Public Function ExecuteCommandQuery(ByRef oCMD As OracleClient.OracleCommand) As DataTable
    oCMD.Connection = _oConn

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    'exception if one occured'
    Dim DBException As Exception = Nothing

    Try
        'get an adapter'
        Dim cmd As New OracleDataAdapter(oCMD)
        'Fill the data table and ket a count of records returned'
        cmd.Fill(dt)

    Catch ex As Exception
        'capture exception, and rethrow after properly closing the Oracle Connection'
        DBException = ex
    Finally
        _oConn.Close()
    End Try

    'if exception occured, rethrow'
    If DBException IsNot Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception( _
            String.Format("A database error occured: {0} " + _
                          Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + " --- " + _
                          Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + _
                          " Your query: {1}" + _
                          Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + " --- " + _
                          Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + _
                          " Your Parameters: " + Environment.NewLine + "{2}" _
                          , DBException.ToString(), oCMD.CommandText, GenerateParameterErrorInfo(oCMD)))
    End If

    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for it to make debugging convenient so that I get the sql with the exact syntax executed and do not need to go to visual studio and copy the exception message and execute it in sql server.

Comment: That is how I use it.  When an exception is thrown (I use ASP.Net) I get the full exception plus the full query with all parameters right on the screen.  Then I copy them into Toad/SQL Server Management Studio and execute it by hand (if I can't see just by looking at it why it's broke).

Does my answer help or is there a way I could modify it so that it would?